# Material-UI, React Grid Component responsive layout problem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got a problem with Grid component from Material-UI.
Even if my Grid items components has the same props, they acting in different way on small resolution.
One of the Grid items is not stretching to the full width for some reason.

Here is how it looks like:
[Three different resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLvpV.png)

Here is my components code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Typography, Container, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ButtonWrapper } from '../styledComponents/styledComponents';

import useStyles from './addCoinForm.styles';

const AddTransactionForm = () => {

  const classes = useStyles(); 

  // ...
  // not related code deleted
  // ...

  return ( 
    <>
      <Container component="div">
        <form className={classes.transactionForm} autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          
          <Typography variant="h6">
            Add transaction
          </Typography>

          <Grid container justify="space-around">

            <Grid item lg={2} sm={10}>
              <TextField name="ticker" variant="standard" label="Coin ticker" fullWidth value={coinData.ticker} onChange={handleChange} />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item lg={2} sm={10}>
              <TextField select name="type" variant="standard" label="buy / sell" fullWidth value={coinData.type}   onChange={handleChange}>
                <MenuItem value="buy">buy</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="sell">sell</MenuItem>
              </TextField>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item lg={2} sm={10}>
              <TextField name="quantity" variant="standard" label="Quantity" fullWidth value={coinData.quantity} onChange={handleChange} />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item lg={2} sm={10}>
              <TextField name="price" variant="standard" label="Price" fullWidth value={coinData.price} onChange={handleChange} />
            </Grid>

          </Grid>

          <ButtonWrapper>
            <Button variant="contained" className={classes.primaryButton} size="large" type="submit"> Add </Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.secondaryButton} size="large" onClick={clear}> Clear </Button>
          </ButtonWrapper>

        </form>
      </Container>
    </>
   );
}
 
export default AddTransactionForm;
```

And here is my form styles code:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  transactionForm: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    margin: "30px 0"
  }
}));

export default useStyles;
```

Comment: This is happening because of TextField with dropdown. Look at this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8778

Comment: I can't see solution in there. 
And there's nothing about resolution. As I mentioned there is all fine with the TextField select dropdown on other resolutions, there's only a problem below 600px breakpoint.